# In python numpy, how to replace some rows in array A with array B if we know the index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In python numpy, how to replace some rows in array A with array B if we know the index.

For example

we have

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[10,10],[1000, 1000]])
index = [0,2]
```

I want to change **a** to

```
a = np.array([[10,10],[3,4],[1000,1000]])
```

I have considered the funtion np.where but it need to create the bool condition, not very convenient,

Comment: All you need to do is: a[index] = b

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[10,10],[1000, 1000]])
index = [0,2]
a[index] = b
print(a)
```

gives output

```
[[  10   10]
 [   3    4]
 [1000 1000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
a[index] = b
```

For example :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[10,10],[1000, 1000]])
index = [0,2]
a[index] = b
print(a)
```

Result :

```
[[  10   10]
 [   3    4]
 [1000 1000]]
```

Comment: This solution is already provided in another answer. If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python's NumPy library, you can use the numpy.put() method to replace some rows in array A with array B if you know the index. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize array A
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# Initialize array B
B = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])

# Indices of the rows to be replaced in array A
indices = [0, 1]

# Replace rows in array A with rows in array B
np.put(A, indices, B)
print(A)
```

In this example, the first two rows in array A are replaced with the first two rows in array B, so the output will be

```
[[10 20 30]
 [40 50 60]
 [ 7  8  9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `a[indices] = b` or if you want to be more fancy `np.put(a, indices, b)`